# Gab es einen deutschen "posh accent"?

Tags: pronunciation, dialect, accent

Zu Weihnachten lief natürlich wieder "Die Feuerzangenbowle" im Fernsehen. Dieses Jahr habe ich den Film zum ersten Mal wirklich bewusst angesehen, und die Sprechweise von Professor Crey hat mich aufhorchen lassen ([Beispiel](https://youtu.be/XnQ3cCtwGpc)). Diese Aussprache (Schüler -> "Schöler", Schluck -> "Schlock") höre ich sonst eigentlich nur, wenn jemand mehr oder weniger humorvoll Hitler imitieren möchte. Da Crey in einer anderen Szene betrunken in etwas verfällt, was ich als Rheinisch verorten würde, und Hitler Unterricht bei einem Sprachlehrer genommen hat, frage ich mich, ob die Sprechweise aus dem Video zur damaligen Zeit als eine "feine" Art zu sprechen galt, die man sich aneignete oder als Kind der Oberschicht direkt lernte.

Geht der Gedanke in die richtige Richtung oder höre ich zu viel aus einem lustigen Akzent in einer Komödie heraus?

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/904/is-there-an-equivalent-prestige-dialect-of-german-in-the-same-way-received-pronu

Comment: Ich denke, alleine das Wort *Bildungsbürgertum* ist ein schönes deutsches Wort, das eine Menge, was hinter diesem "ich will meine Bildung zeigen" steckt, zum Ausdruck bringt.

Comment: Vielleicht solltest du erläutern, was genau mit »posh accent« gemeint ist?

Comment: Eine Art der Aussprache, die allgemein mit Oberschicht und hoher Bildung in Verbindung gebracht wird.

Comment: Wenn ihr euch heute Bild- und Tonaufzeichnungen aus der ersten Hälfte des letzten Jahrhunderts anschaut, bedenkt bitte, dass die Leute, die dort sprachen, aufgrund der noch in den Kinderschuhen steckenden Technik dazu angehalten wurden, extrem deutlich und artikuliert zu sprechen - Ansonsten hätte sie einfach keiner verstanden. Nicht umsonst gingen viele Sternchen der Stummfilmära mit dem Beginn des Tonfilms unter, weil sie Stimmen oder ein Idiom hatten, das einfach lächerlich oder unverständlich war. Natürlich ist das in dieser Szene der FZB vollkommen überzogen.

Comment: Pfeiffer und andere Charaktere sprechen aber durchaus "normal" auch nach heutigen Standards.

Comment: Ich spreche eher von Hitler - der sprach früher.

Comment: "posh accent" kann man übersetzen mit "vornehmer Akzent". Klingt m.E. aber oft eher affektiert oder manieriert, also übertrieben, wie einige sich eben "vornehm" vorstellen.

Comment: Ein deutscher "vornehmer" Akzent für Deutsch als Ganzes konnte sich, denke ich, kaum entwickeln, weil die jeweiligen vornehmen Kreise immer stark in regionalsprachliche Sprachzusammenhänge eingebettet waren. Jedoch kann man innerhalb der Regionaldialekte durchaus "posh"-Varianten finden. Bekannt ist zum Beispiel bis heute das sogenannte **Honoratiorenschwäbisch** - eine Sprachform, die sich zwar lexikalisch an die Schriftsprache anzunähern versucht, jedoch in der Aussprache (v.a. Vokale) in der schwäbischen Umgebungskultur verhaftet ist.

Comment: Zur Einordnung der Sprechweise ist es möglicherweise sinnvoll, sich nicht nur auf Adolf Hitler zu konzentrieren, sondern sich auch politische Zeitgenossen anzuhören. (Empfehlenswert z.B. "Berlin calls the World" auf Youtube) Dabei wird man feststellen,  das Pathos und "egagierte, deutliche Sprache" keine Eigenarten von Hitler waren.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ich nehme die Aussprache des Professor Crey ebenso wahr wie der Fragesteller. Kurze Recherche aus eigenem Interesse ergibt, dass das Phänomen auch schon in der Literatur diskutiert wurde.

*Zimmermann* berichtet anhand verschiedener Beispiele aus der Literatur über eine "manierte" phonetische Übertreibung des Standarddeutschen. Als Beispiel verweist er etwa auf die Erzieherin Therese Weichbrodt in den Buddenbrooks, deren Aussprache folgendermaßen beschrieben wird (id., S. 138):

> In „allen ihren Bewegungen [lag] ein Nachdruck, der zwar possierlich, aber durchaus respektgebietend wirkte. Dazu trug in hohem Grade auch ihre Sprache bei. Sie sprach exakt und dialektfrei, klar, bestimmt und mit sorgfältiger Betonung jedes Konsonanten. Den Klang der Vokale aber übertrieb sie sogar in einer Weise, daß sie z. B. nicht 'Butterkruke', sondern 'Botter-' oder gar 'Batterkruke' sprach und ihr eigensinnig kläffendes Hündchen nicht 'Bobby' sondern 'Babby' rief.“

Aus dem Roman lässt sich folgendes abweichendes Vokalinventar feststellen: [u] > [ɔ] (Botter, forchtbar), ü [y] > ö [ø] (Böchse, glöcklich), [ɔ] > [a] (Beschaf [statt Bischof]). (Id., S. 139)

Als weitere Beispiele nennt *Zimmermann* u.a. eben jenen Professor Crey, der seine Vokale mit "denselben überzogenen, manierten Öffnungen" spreche (id., S. 140). Dies wurde ja hier auch schon in der Frage deutlich. Ähnliche Formen dieser hochgestochenen, hyperfeinen Betonung lassen sich sodann in einer Reihe von Beschreibungen "feiner" Charaktere nachvollziehen, u.a. bei Adolf Glaßbrenner (id., S. 141 ff.).

Ich denke ("educated guess") ausdrücklich nicht, dass dies zu irgendeiner Zeit ein verbreitetes Phänomen war. Dann gäbe es dafür viel mehr Evidenz; es würde sich in diesem Fall außerdem gerade nicht zur (Über)zeichnung bestimmter Charaktere eignen. Sehr wohl darf man aber, denke ich, davon ausgehen, dass es - gewiss auch in schwächerer Form als in der naturgemäß zur Zuspitzung neigenden Belletristik -, vorkam. Viele der Beispiele von *Zimmermann* - die ja nicht alle so einen Einleitungstext wie in den Buddenbrooks haben - bezeugen m.E. recht deutlich, dass der Rezipient auch ohne kontextuelle Hilfe durchaus wusste, was gemeint war.

---

*Zimmermann*, Phonetische Beobachtungen zum gezierten Sprachgebrauch im Deutschen und Englischen: Nach Zeugnissen aus der fiktionalen und biographischen Literatur, Zeitschrift für Dialektologie und Linguistik 1998, S. 129-151 (über [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/40481841) zugänglich)

Answer (score 5):

Zuerst: Ja, ich denke es gab bisweilen ein Deutsch des aufstrebenden Bildungsbürgertums, das dem, was im Film gezeigt wurde (und natürlich stark übertrieben ist) nahe kommt, und stark und sogar übertrieben (aber nicht "anders" als in normaler Sprache) akzentuiert gesprochen wurde. Vollkommene Dialektfreiheit is ebenfalls ein Merkmal einer solchen Sprechweise.

Es ist allerdings meiner Ansicht nach nicht vergleichbar mit dem, was im Britischen Englisch unter "posh language" verstanden wird und versucht bei weitem nicht so stark *sozialen Status* sondern eher *Bildung* zu signalisieren. Und wie immer gab es auch Leute, die es mit Hyperkorrektur übertrieben.

Das manierte, akzentuierte Sprechen wird z.B. (Chor)sängern auch heute noch beigebracht, um dafür zu sorgen, dass der Gesang in einem Chor überhaupt (z.B. auch in der eher schwierigen akustischen Umgebung einer Kirche) noch zu verstehen ist. Man legt Wert auf eine deutliche Aussprache, vermeidet, dass Konsonanten verschluckt und Vokale verschliffen werden, bekämpft also alles, was sich als "schlampige Aussprache" anhört. Eine solche Aussprache kann sich im normalen Gespräch schon sehr "posh" anhören, ist aber kein besonderer Akzent, sondern eher eine besonders *deutliche* Aussprache.

Natürlich neigen besonders Sprachlehrer (wie die erwähnte Erzieherin aus den Buddenbrooks) zu einer übertriebenen Manieriertheit in der Sprache - Schließlich müssen sie ihren Schülern ja die Unterschiede besonders deutlich machen. Man kann also eher von einer "Berufskrankheit" reden.

Wikipedia sagt:

> Sprech-Eigentümlichkeiten der Romanfigur Professor Crey übernahm Spoerl aus der 1875 veröffentlichten Humoreske *Der Besuch im Karzer* von Ernst Eckstein.

Schon 1875, als das Buch geschrieben wurde, handelte es sich also um Klamauk - mit "posh" hat das nichts zu tun.

Außerdem ist mir nicht ganz einleuchtend, was Hitler mit der ganzen Frage zu tun hat. Hört man sich zeitgenössische Aufnahmen von irgendwelchen anderen Politikern (z.B. Kurt Schumacher) an, kann man denselben Duktus und Pathos heraushören.

Answer (score 2):

### Hitlers ersten drei Jahrzehnte (Sprachprägung)

Hitlers Eltern stammen beide aus der Gegend rund um Zwettl in Niederösterreich, nahe der Grenze zu Böhmen. Sein Vater war Zollbeamter und wurde nach Braunau, zur Grenze zu Deutschland versetzt. Daher lebten die Hitlers in Braunau am Inn als der kleine Adolf geboren wurde.

Weil die Eltern oft umzogen, wuchs Adolf an verschiedenen Orten in Oberösterreich auf, darunter auch in Linz. Später, als junger Mann, wollte er in Wien Kunst studieren, schaffte aber die Aufnahmeprüfung zur Kunstakademie nicht. Er lebte zu dieser Zeit abwechselnd in Linz und Wien, oft in billigen Wohnheimen.

Erst 1913, Adolf war bereits 24 Jahre alt, verließ er Österreich. Er wollte nämlich dem österreichischen Wehrdienst entfliehen. Er blieb dabei aber weiterhin jenem Sprachraum treu, der durch bayrische Dialekte geprägt ist, er zog nämlich nach München.

Ein Jahr drauf, der erste Weltkrieg war gerade ausgebrochen, trat Hitler freiwillig der Bayrischen Armee bei, der er bis Kriegsende, und sogar noch einige Jahre darüber hinaus angehörte. (Offenbar störte seine österreichische Staatsbürgschaft nicht, er war auch nicht der einzige Österreicher in der bayrischen Armee.)

Nach Kriegsende lebte er wieder in München und begann erst um 1920 (damals war er 31) vermehrt nach Berlin zu reisen, also schön langsam den bayrischen Dialekt-Sprachraum zu verlassen.

Die ersten drei Jahrzehnte seines Lebens waren also durchgängig durch ein soziales Umfeld geprägt, in dem bayrische Dialekte vorherrschend und damit prägend für Hitlers Aussprache waren.

---

### die bekannte Sprechweise Hitlers

Wenn man historische Tonaufnahmen von Hitlers Reden hört, hört man aber etwas ganz anderes. Man sollte eigentlich ja aufgrund seiner Herkunft vermuten, einen österreichisch-bayrischen Akzent zu hören, das ist aber keineswegs der Fall.

Hitler hat sehr großen Aufwand betrieben, seine Herkunft zu verschleiern und zu verwischen. Die niederösterreichischen Heimatdörfer seiner Eltern und Großeltern (Döllersheim und Strones) wurden zu militärische Sperrzonen erklärt, und sämtliche Gedenktafeln (z.B. auf Friedhöfen), die Rückschlüsse auf seine Familie zuließen, wurden zerstört, ebenso alle Standes-Dokumente in diesen Gemeinden. (Historiker fanden aber in anderen Quellen  noch immer Indizien für Inzucht unter Hitlers Vorfahren.)

Daher wundert es nicht, dass er auch seine österreichisch-bayrisch Aussprache ablegen wollte, um auch dem Klang seiner Worte nach als strammer und führungsstarker Deutscher wahrgenommen zu werden.

Aus Tagebüchern des aus Hamburg stammenden Opernsängers Paul Devrient geht hervor, dass Devrient im Jahr 1932 dem damals bereits 43-jährigen Hitler einige Monate lang Sprachunterricht gegeben hat. (Das Talent für Rhetorik brachte Hitler selbst mit.) Allerdings ist nicht anzunehmen, dass dieser späte Unterricht allein der Grund für Hitlers Sprechweise war. Hitler hat schon davor so gesprochen, wie man es von ihm kennt.

Es ist viel eher davon auszugehen, dass sich Hitler selbst schon in jungen Jahren sehr bemüht hat, sich eine möglichst stramme deutsche Aussprache anzueignen.

Ganz offensichtlich muss damals, in den Jahren zwischen 1920 und 1940, ganz allgemein die Ansicht vorgeherrscht haben, dass die in der Frage beschriebene Art zu sprechen, und die man heute vor allem bei Hitler-Parodien hört, die beste Art ist, um ganz besonders stramm-deutsch zu klingen. Zumindest muss Hitler das geglaubt haben, und man hat es ihn ganz offenbar abgenommen.

Ich vermute hinter dieser Sprechweise eine Tradition, die in der breiten Bevölkerung zwar bekannt, aber nicht aktiv gesprochen wurde. Meiner Auffassung nach ist es eher eine aus militärischen Kreisen stammende Sprechweise, die Autorität vermitteln sollte. Daher passt sie auch ganz gut zu einem Professor dieser Zeit, der kraft seiner Rede besondere Strenge und Führungsstärke demonstrieren will.

In seinem Bemühen, dem vermeintlichen Ideal ausdrucksstarker Sprache möglichst nahe zu kommen, hat es Hitler dabei wohl etwas übertrieben. Ein Phänomen, das als *Hyperkorrektur* bekannt ist.

Auch zu bedenken ist, dass der Film *»Die Feuerzangenbowle«*, obwohl die Handlung ungefähr rund um das Jahr 1890 anzusiedeln ist, im Jahr 1944 in die Kinos kam. Gedreht wurde er zwischen März und Juni 1943. Daher gehe ich persönlich davon aus, dass Hitlers Art zu sprechen auch Einfluss auf die Sprechweise hatte, die manchen Rollen im Film eigen waren.

Comment: Was Hitlers Lebensgeschichte mit "posh accent" zu tun hat, verstehe ich, ehrlich gesagt, nicht.

Comment: @tofro: Ich versuche in dieser Geschichte nachvollziehbar zu machen, wie Hitler, und in weiterer Folge Professor Crey, zu der Aussprache kamen, nach der sich der Fragesteller erkundigt hat.

Comment: Ich habe ehrlich gesagt schon in der Frage nicht wirklich verstanden, was Hitlers Aussprache mit der Aussprache von Professor Crey zu tun hat.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich bezweifle stark, dass es irgendeinen Zusammenhang zwischen der Sprechweise des Lehrers Crey (die purer Klamauk war) und der von Adolf Hitler (die leider alles andre als Klamauk war) gab.

Comment: @johnl. Der Zusammenhang ist, dass die manierierte Aussprache des Professors im Film nicht unähnlich ist der manierierten Aussprache des Adolf Hitler in den Tondokumenten, die man davon hat. Diese beiden Charaktere, beide aus ähnlicher Zeit, sind die bekanntesten Vertreter solcher Sprechweise. - Es gibt natürlich auch andere, aber die sind weniger bekannt. Siehe z.B. die Gedichte in "Starckdeutsch" von Matthias Koeppel.

Comment: Ich finde den Hinweis auf Aussprachetraditionen in Militärkreisen einleuchtend und weiterer Verfolgung wert. Man bedenke auch die Notwendigkeit, bei Ansprachen vor größerem Publikum (Wirtshausversammlung, Kasernenhof) damals noch ohne Lautsprechersystem verständlich zu sein.

Comment: Ich finde, dass Hitlers Lebensgeschichte hier absolut unpassend ist und nicht hingehört. Wenn auch wahrscheinlich unbeabsichtigt, bekommt der Abschnitt durch die Nennung bei seinem Vornamen und mehrere Auslassungen und Ungenauigkeiten auch noch etwas Verharmlosendes. BTW. Wenn Hitler bis 1913 in Österreich gelebt hat, hat er ja wohl die ersten 24 Jahre seines Lebens im österreichischen und nicht im bairischen Sprachraum verbracht.

Comment: @clemens Das, was in Österreich gesprochen wird, wird allgemein (ausser ein paar regionalen Ausnahmen, wie z.B. Vorarlberg) dem bairischen Sprachraum zugeordnet. Politische Grenzen und Sprachgrenzen sind nicht identisch.

Comment: @tofro: Mag sein, ist dann aber durch die Weite des Begriffs bzw. des bairischen Sprachraums auch wenig erhellend. Wie du das in deinem ersten Kommentar bereits geschrieben hast, sind die Hinweise auf Hitlers Vita völlig themenfern. Dabei sind auch noch die historischen Zusammenhänge sehr ungenau und unvollständig. Abgesehen davon halte ich z. B. den letzten Absatz für extrem fragwürdig. Der Professor ist eine komische Figur im Film, für den 1943/44 wohl niemand mehr Hitler als Vorbild genommen hätte.

Answer (score 2):

Nach meiner Erfahrung gibt es im deutschen Sprachraum keine so klare Unterscheidung der "class" wie in England bzw. Großbritannien. Ich lebe in Kanada und nach meiner Beobachtung gibt es diesen Zusammenhang zwischen Akzent und Klassenzugehörigkeit hier nicht, auch nicht in den USA oder Australien. Das wird vielmehr als typisch britischer Snobismus angesehen (In 'My Fair Lady' wird erwähnt, dass ein Engländer nur 30 Sekunden braucht um seinen Gesprächspartner in eine Klasse einzuordnen).
In Deutschland sind die Dialekte (und Akzente?) doch eher regional.
Ich bin in Mecklenburg aufgewachsen und spreche ein relativ neutrales Deutsch. Ich habe oft die Ansicht gehört, dass im Raum Hannover das beste (Hoch-)Deutsch gesprochen würde. Früher hieß es mal, dass die Sprecher der 20 Uhr Ausgabe der Tagesschau die hochdeutsche Aussprache definieren würden. In Österreich wäre es das Burgtheater.

Ich denke, dass ein starker Dialekt im öffentlichen Leben außerhalb der Heimatregion eher ein Nachteil ist. Personen, die kein Hochdeutsch sprechen, wird je nach Situation ein gewisser intellektueller Malus zugeschrieben.
Aus der Aussage kann man jetzt jede Menge Witze über baierische oder württembergische Politiker generieren. Vielleicht spielt da aber auch die Arroganz meiner norddeutschen Herkunft eine zu große Rolle.

Zusammenfassend: Wie so oft im Deutschen oder in Deutschland, hebt man sich nicht mit einer Aussprache aus der Masse positiv heraus ("posh"); vielmehr wird eine Person für Abweichung von der Norm benachteiligt.
In England gibt's das Queen's English und den Akzent der Oberschicht, den die sogenannten Eliten in wenigen ausgesuchten Internaten (Eton) erlernen. Wer da später noch rein will, hat es ganz ganz schwer. Die Sprache separiert sofort.

Zum Glück gibt's das in Deutschland nicht in der Weise. Privat finden alle den baierischen Dialekt sowieso "süß".