# Deutsche Mundart die mit Macht / Ehre assoziiert wird?

Tags: pronunciation, accent

Ich möchte gern wissen, ob es beim deutschen Sprachraum sowas gibt wie einen gewissen Dialekt oder eine gewisse Mundart, oder vielleicht auch nur kleinere Abweichungen zur Aussprache einer Person, die mit Macht bzw. Ehre o.Ä. assoziiert werden können, auch unbewusst vielleicht, wie z.B. das was im GB als "posh" bezeichnet wird, was sich auch wohl mehr oder weniger dem Willen des Sprecher oder der Sprecherin nach zur Verfügung steht (d.h. es muss nicht eine angeborene, ständige Mundsart sein oder so, kann ich mir vorstellen).

Ich freue mich auf Antworten und Meinungen zu dem Thema.

Comment: Eine »Redensart« ist ein »Sprichwort« o. ä., Dialekt und Akzent sind etwas anderes. Wenn ich Dich richtig verstehe, möchtest Du also wissen, ob es unter den deutschsprachigen Akzenten und Dialekten (platt, Standard, schwäbisch, kölsch, sächsisch, bayrisch, österreichisch, schweizerisch ...) einen – oder mehrere – gibt, die von einem Großteil der deutschsprachigen Bevölkerung mit einem hohen gesellschaftlichen Status assoziiert werden? Ich nehme an, dass Du so etwas meinst wie die Aussprache hochrangiger Politiker im Vereinigten Königreich?

Comment: Genau, ich habe die Frage bearbeitet, danke.

Comment: Gibt es Aspekte Deiner Frage, die von https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40864, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/904 oder https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5808 nicht beantwortet werden?

Comment: Unbenommen aller gesellschaftlichen Unterschiede zwischen GB und D : Was ich am ehesten noch *heute* als "posh accent im Deutschen" akzeptieren würde, wäre vielleicht das "Hamburger Hochdeutsch" (nicht die Mundart), wie es z.B. in den Buddenbrooks gesprochen wird (oder wie der Altkanzler Schmidt sprach).

Comment: In den verlinkten Antworten wird zwar beantwortet, was "akzent- und dialektfreies" Hochdeutsch ist, aber nicht, was ein entsprechendes Gegenstück zu britischem "upper-class-English" (RP) ist (ich bezweifle, dass es dieses Gegenstück im Deutschen gibt). Ich finde, das ist definitiv nicht dasselbe.

Comment: Wo gibt es denn eine Mundart, die angeboren wird?

Comment: @userunknown Du darfst bei offensichtlichen Zweitsprachlern ruhig ein bisschen großzügiger sein. Wahrscheinlich ist gemeint, dass man in eine Mundart *hinein*geboren wird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falls du nach einem Dialekt oder einer Mundart suchst, die einem Zuhörer (vermeintlich?) sofort Bildungsniveau und sozialen Status des Sprechers verraten würde: Das gibt es im Deutschen nicht (zumindestens nicht so, wie man z.B. in GB *Received Pronounciation* als "die Aussprache der Mächtigen" verstehen würde).

Es gibt das dialekt- und akzentfreie regionalneutrale *Hochdeutsch*, das man i.A. in die Gegend um Hannover verorten würde, und das allgemein als "regional unbeeinflusste Hochsprache" anerkannt ist. Das ist aber nicht gleichzeitig (wie z.B. traditionell in GB RP) "die Sprache der Mächtigen", sondern einfach nur ein akzentfreies Deutsch, sozusagen "der gemeinsame Nenner", der (nicht-)Akzent, mit dem Radio- und Fernsehsprecher sprechen.

Gesellschaftlicher Status und Bildungsniveau werden vom Zuhörer eher nach Richtigkeit von Grammatik, Wortwahl und Vielfalt der Ausdrucksweise eingeordnet. Verwendet jemand z.B. den Genitiv (im Alltagsdeutsch vieler Regionen ziemlich ausgestorben), und das auch noch richtig, würde der Zuhörer den Sprecher eher in eine bildungsnahe Schicht einsortieren (oder sagen, dass er sich "geschraubt ausdrückt"). Dabei ist es meiner Meinung nach vollkommen egal, ob der Sprecher Hochdeutsch mit einem leichten bairischen, fränkischen, oder gar keinem Akzent spricht.

Ich gleite mal ein bißchen in die Mutmaßung ab: Deutschland ist aus einem Flickenteppich von Fürstentümern und Königreichen entstanden, mit Universitäten auf jedem Flicken - Jeder Dialekt hatte seinen eigenen Bildungsstandort - und natürlich einen eigenen König, damit keine Machtkonzentration in einem bestimmten Dialektraum wie z.B. in Großbritannien. Auch heute noch darf der Ministerpräsident von Baden-Württemberg fröhlich vor sich hinschwäbeln und der von Bayern -fränkeln - Auch wenn der Hochdeutsch-Verfechter Joseph von Sonnenfels bei einem Besuch am Wiener Hof 1784 bemerkte, dass

> die best gekleidete Dame der höheren Gesellschaft so pöbelhaft rede wie ihre Küchenmagd.

Comment: Ok, ich dachte sowas in der Art wie z.B. das rollende R, das etwas kraftvoll klingen mag (und aus diesem Grund auch wohl von den Nazis eingesetzt wurde), es muss ja vielleicht kein ganzer Dialekt sein der meine Frage betreffen würde

Comment: @sermonionx Der sprachliche Pathos, den Nazis gerne verwendet haben, war nach dem Krieg und ist bis heute noch ziemlich aus der Mode. Er würde heute wohl eher  spontan berechtigtes Misstrauen hervorrufen.

Comment: Würde man vielleicht sagen, dass das akzentfreie Hochdeutsch is das mächtigste oder respektvollste im deutschen Sprachraum?

Comment: Nein. Dann hast du die Antwort nicht gelesen. Das akzentfreie Hochdeutsch ist das, mit dem man am wenigsten Gefahr läuft, sich zu blamieren. (Was nicht heißen würde, dass man sich mit einem Akzent automatisch blamieren würde. Aber Hochdeutsch ist einfach nicht mit Macht, Respekt oder Einfluß verknüpft.)

Comment: @sermonionx Wegen des rollenden "R" empfehle ich https://www.reddit.com/r/de/comments/cj51wx/wird_das_r_rollen_mit_der_zungenspitze_wegen/ zur Lektüre. Ein solcher Tonfall erinnert mich in der Tat an Hitler, was zwar zu seinem Drang nach Macht passt, aber wohl eher seiner österreichischen Herkunft geschuldet sein dürfte.

Comment: @tofro "Er würde heute wohl eher spontan berechtigtes Misstrauen hervorrufen." Wollen wir mal hoffen, dass das zumindest bei einer Mehrheit der Hörer noch zutriftt.

Comment: Nein, es gibt kein «einfach nur ein akzentfreies Deutsch». Das angeblich «akzentfreie» Deutsch ist sehr wohl die Sprache der Macht, nämlich der preussischen Oberschicht. Bezeichnenderweise hat sich diejenige Aussprache, die heute als «akzentfrei» gilt, sich ja mit dem politischen Aufstieg Preussens im 19. Jahrhundert etabliert.

Comment: @mach Das ist, ehrlich gesagt, eine unzulässige Verallgemeinerung - Im tiefsten Bayern oder in der Schweiz wird "preussisches Hochdeutsch" (was auch immer das sein sollte, die meisten "Preußen", die ich kenne, haben irgendwie berlinert) mit Sicherheit nicht mit "Sprache der Macht" assoziiert - eher im Gegenteil.

Comment: @tofro: Du hast Recht, ich habe etwas dick aufgetragen. Ich hätte besser sagen sollen, das angeblich «akzentfreie» Deutsch sei die Sprache der preussischen Oberschicht _gewesen,_ nämlich derjenigen des 19. Jahrhunderts. Ich bleibe jedoch beim Downvote, denn «einfach nur ein akzentfreies Deutsch» gibt es trotzdem nicht.

Answer (score 1):

In Wien gibt bzw. gab es sowas wie ein Schönbrunner-Deutsch, das sehr gern von der high society bzw. generell in der Nobelgegend (Döbling, Währing, Grinzing) von Wien gesprochen wird. Es ist aber eher die Art und die leicht nasale Aussprache. In Wien gibt es mehrere Dialekte, zum Beispiel das Meidlinger "L", das man eher mit der nicht so gehobenen Gesellschaftsklasse in Verbindung bringt.
Die Unterschiede sind aber heute nicht mehr so stark ausgeprägt, da sich die Gesellschaft stark vermischt hat und sehr multikulturell ist.